# Getting UNEXPECTED_END_OF_QUERY Error with Google Ads API Ruby client library

Tags: ruby-on-rails, google-ads-api

So I'm using ruby client library. Version of gem 'google-ads-googleads' is 21.0.0 and Google Ads API version is 13.
After initialising client with my credentials, I try to query one of the Google Ads Get Account Hierarchy endpoint, I get Error message:

`<Google::Ads::GoogleAds::V13::Errors::GoogleAdsFailure: errors: [<Google::Ads::GoogleAds::V13::Errors::GoogleAdsError: error_code: <Google::Ads::GoogleAds::V13::Errors::ErrorCode: query_error: :UNEXPECTED_END_OF_QUERY>, message: "Error in query: unexpected end of query.">], request_id: "koqtfsaS6CTB0FxlCHucKg">`

```
client = Google::Ads::GoogleAds::GoogleAdsClient.new do |config|
      config.client_id = client_id
      config.client_secret = client_secret
      config.refresh_token = access_token
      config.developer_token = developer_token
end
google_ads_service = client.service.google_ads
query = <<~QUERY
      SELECT
        customer_client.client_customer,
        customer_client.level,
        customer_client.manager,
        customer_client.descriptive_name,
        customer_client.currency_code,
        customer_client.time_zone,
        customer_client.id
      FROM customer_client
      WHERE customer_client.level <= 1
    QUERY
begin
   request = google_ads_service.search_stream do |search|
        search.customer_id = '8148704352'
        search.query = query
        search.page_size = 100
    end
    request.each do |response|                   
       response.results.each do |row|
           puts row
       end
    end
rescue Google::Ads::GoogleAds::Errors::GoogleAdsError => e
    puts "Error message: #{e.failure}"
end
```

I tried

```
query = <<~SQL
  SELECT
    customer_client.client_customer,
    customer_client.level,
    customer_client.manager,
    customer_client.descriptive_name,
    customer_client.currency_code,
    customer_client.time_zone,
    customer_client.id
  FROM customer_client
  WHERE customer_client.level <= 1
SQL
```

I also tried enclosing query in single quotes like
query_with_single_quotes = ''' + query + '''
but the error doesn't go away.

Comment: @dbugger Yes that was a typo. I corrected it. But I was not getting error because of that

Comment: query validates -- I'd just print out the query string to make sure it doesn't have any strangeness and also would try it as a single line

Comment: what happens if you do `search_stream(customer_id: ...., query: query, page_size: 100)`? like a function call with the params instead of the block syntax. All examples I can see in the gem's source are with a keyword params instead of a block https://github.com/googleads/google-ads-ruby/blob/0df9947436fc813b520a13a83e4ae91816a8a5d8/examples/misc/navigate_search_result_pages_caching_tokens.rb#L47

Answer (score 0):

Try to use SQL.squish instead of query:

```
query = <<~SQL.squish
  SELECT
    customer_client.client_customer,
    customer_client.level,
    customer_client.manager,
    customer_client.descriptive_name,
    customer_client.currency_code,
    customer_client.time_zone,
    customer_client.id
  FROM customer_client
  WHERE customer_client.level <= 1
SQL
```

By the way, this project has active record?
If it has, you can just write something like this:

```
CustomerClient.where('level <= 1')
              .pluck(:id, :client_customer, :level, :manager,
                     :descriptive_name, :currency_code, :time_zone)
```